# Using globals for CommonJS config files

Tags: javascript, module, npm, commonjs

Right now I'm using a CommonJS module to set some global variables in my scripts rather than setting them manually in each script.

index.spec.js

```
/*globals browser, by, element*/
require('./config.js')();

describe('exampleApp', function() {
    'use strict';

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080/');
    });

    describe('index view', function() {
        it('should have a title', function() {
            expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('Example App');
        });
    });
});
```

config.js

```
/*globals global*/
module.exports = function() {
    'use strict';

    global.chai = require('chai');
    global.promised = require('chai-as-promised');
    global.expect = global.chai.expect;

    global.chai.use(global.promised);
}();
```

However, using the global object here seems like bad practice.  Is there a better way?  Maybe a way to load variables scoped locally scoped to the file I'm `require`-ing into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just export a config object and require it in all the files that need the configuration object?

```
'use strict';

var config = {};
config.chai = require('chai');
config.promised = require('chai-as-promised');
config.expect = config.chai.expect;
config.chai.use(config.promised);

module.exports = config;
```

And then just require this in all the files that use the configuration:

`var config = require('config.js');`

Comment: I guess that is the best alternative.  Sadly `expect` gets used so frequently I need to overwrite the global rather than just use `config.expect`.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.